# How to create buttons after each line of the list?

Tags: javascript, button, createelement

I'd like to display a list of skills and values of a player, and create an increment and decrement button after each line to increase or decrease the value. I've tried to gather lines from other questions related to this problem, but I'm a beginner and can't solve it.
Here it is my code:

```
var text = "<ul>";
var i = 0;

for (i; i < this.skillPoints.length; i++) {
  text +=
    "<li>" +
    this.skillPoints[i]._name +
    " value is: " +
    this.skillPoints[i]._value +
    "</li></br>";

    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));

    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    btn.innerHTML = "Increment";
    entry.appendChild(btn);
}

text += "</ul>";
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: Well, either use `innerHTML` or `appendChild` and you are good to go. The text you are adding as a textNode, that is why it does not work.

Comment: If you mean I should delete the line:
entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text)); 

It makes no error but the buttons don't appear. Did I misunderstand you? Thanks

Comment: Have you look at developer console for any error ?

Comment: It might not throw an error, but it is not doing what you think it does. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up alot of functios which would work individually. Either decide on adding the text as `innerHTML` or adding the elementy by `appendChild(document.createElement(x))`. Also `createTextNode()` creates HTML encoded output and not what you seek. Last, you should wait to add all to the DOM until the output is completed.

This is a corrected example as close to your code as possible.

```js
//REM: For testing
var skillPoints = [
 {_name: 'Skill 1', _value: 'a'},
 {_name: 'Skill 2', _value: 'b'}
];

//REM: Start of the list
var text = "<ul>";

//REM: Removed "this" for testing purposes
for(var i=0; i < skillPoints.length; i++){
  text += "<li>";
  text += skillPoints[i]._name;
  text += " value is: ";
  text += skillPoints[i]._value;
  text += "</li></br>";
  text += "<button> Increment </button>";

  //REM: Not required.. the li gets added as string already in this case. Use either or but not both.
  //var entry = document.createElement('li');

  //REM: First, textnode adds encoded HTML and second, the list is not complete yet
  //REM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode
  //entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
};

text += "</ul>";

//REM: Now that the ul is complete, we add it to the DOM
//REM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', text);
```